# Как собрать x64 в юнити?

Tags: unity3d

Я уже делал это, и всё работало, но после включения мной unity ads после загрузки бундла появилась ошибка, что приложение содержит только 32 битный нативный код. Я убрал рекламу и снова загрузил приложение, но это не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте окно "Player Settings" из окна "Build Settings", либо Edit => Project Settings => Player Settings. Разверните там вкладку Other Settings. Внутри нужно изменить Scripting Backend на IL2CPP и поставить галочку для ARM64 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если бы Вы внимательно прочитали основную часть вопроса, Вы бы увидели, что я это уже делал. И про то, что Вы показали на скрине, я тоже знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Я убрал флажок x86, вроде бы это помогло